# Significantly bigger size of reports

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have recently upgraded from version 4.0.0 to 5.6.3. In the latest version the *.jtl file generated at the end of the test run is almost twice the size of the reports generated by the older version. Are there any changes related to the logging or collecting additional metric which may contribute to the bigger size? This is the only argument I am using while executing the tests:

```
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -n -t
```

Expected to have almost the same size of the report but obviously it is twice the size.

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the [changelog](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) or comparing [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)?

A quick experiment shows that JMeter 5.6.3 saves URL

[image]

But it's for "vanilla" setup, not sure what else you have amended in order to get .jtl results files differences.

If you don't need URL in the .jtl results file you need to run your test like:

```
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=false ....
```

if you need to make the change permanent - add the above line to *user.properties* file.

More information on JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)